# Limits with two unknowns (x,h)

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a question where there are two unknows ($x$ and $h$)
How should I approach the question?

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x+h}} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}}{h}\tag{1}$$

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\dfrac{x-h}{(x-h-3)^2} - \dfrac{x}{(x-3)^2}}{h}\tag{2}$$

Comment: Only the $h$ has a limit taken. They both match definition of derivative formulas

Comment: well the limit is only for $h$, you do not need to worry what happens with $x$ it has to be treated like a constant ; this is also the first principle derivative definition to $ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}} $

Comment: @coffeemath since it’s the start of the year & this is the type of question you might be asked in a high-school level calculus course, I’m tempted to say this guy doesn’t know what a derivative is.

Comment: @Snacc I see your point but am a bit leary of saying something offensive to a "new contributor" [Haven't read up on how new contributors should be handled...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of a derivative:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(h)}{h}$$

So the basis of your question is asking for the derivative of

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$$
and
$$g(x)=\frac{x}{(x-3)^3}$$

You could simply apply the formulas and theorems regarding both limits, but here is a more rigprous approach of the first

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x+h}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}}{h}\\
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x+h}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{x+h}}{\sqrt[3]{x+h}\sqrt[3]{x}}}{h}\\
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{x+h}}{h\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x}}$$

Recall $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{x+h}}{h\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)^2}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)^2}}=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{x-(x+h)}{(h\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x})(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)^2})}}\\
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-h}{{(h\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x})(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)x}+\sqrt[3]{(x+h)^2})}}=\frac{-1}{(\sqrt[3]{x^2})(\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}+\sqrt[3]{x^2})}\\
\frac{-1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}(3\sqrt[3]{x^2})}=\boxed{\frac{-1}{3x\sqrt[3]{x}}}$$

Comment: The other limit requires more algebra, but it is actually trivial so give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

In each of these limits, you regard $x$ as a fixed constant and let $h\to 0$.